# Webpack rendering coffee script as comments or nothing

Tags: javascript, webpack, coffeescript

I am having trouble getting webpack + coffeescript to work. I have gone as far as trying to create a minimal example to demonstrate my issue. I have tried to replicate the [webpack+coffeescript example](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/coffee-script) with little success.

I should be getting exactly the same code as the example linked above, instead webpack is generating this:

```
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

console.log(__webpack_require__(1));

/***/ }),
/* 1 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

// module.exports =
//  cool: "stuff"
//  answer: 42
//  external: require "./cup2.coffee"
//  again: require "./cup2"


/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```

Why is the code commented out? This behavior is only observable when running webpack with --mode none, in production is just renders an empty module.

If you want to try reproducing this locally here is my [test project](https://github.com/honzasterba/webpack-coffeescript-test), you can use build.sh script to generate the code.

Comment: If it isn't commented out, it would be a syntax error...

Comment: hmm, thats true, so the coffeescript is not getting transpiled into JS, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was the literate: true option in coffee-loader. Why this had such an effect I do not know.

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.coffee$/,
            loader: "coffee-loader"
        }
    ]
}
```

is the fix.

Comment: Literate Coffeescript is code written inside a markdown file. The idea is a heavily commented and easy to read/parse format. But for the coffeescript to be executed when compiled, it needs to be indented at least 4 spaces (like any code examples inside markdown. See the [docs](https://coffeescript.org/#literate)